# it is possible in visual basic to clear value in my setting (My.Settings.Code1) when timer reaches 0? let say from 30 days countdown

Tags: vb.net

I'm developing a WinForms project that when the timer (30 days) reaches zero, the value in my setting (my.settings.code1) will clear and save so that user cannot enter a specific form.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: You're approaching it wrong; save the date of install somewhere (registry?) and check upon startup how long ago that install date was. If it's more than 30 days, disable your forms. Don't expect that this (or your approach) would form a particularly robust shareware style timeout though - .net exes are trivial to break into. If you want to make a more robust option, yconsider to keep some vital part of the code on a server, and have the EXE ask for it to do work (API call). When the 30 days are up, remove access to the API unless the customer has paid. An internet connection is thus required

Answer (score 0):

A WinForms `Timer` has an `Interval` property of type `Integer` that contains a number of milliseconds. That means that the greatest interval supported is about 24.6 days (if I remember correctly, without calculating it again). That means that you cannot just use a single `Timer` and `Tick` for what you want. It's also unlikely that someone would run a WinForms app for 30 days without exiting anyway.

What I would suggest is that you store the expiry time somewhere that is persisted between sessions. That might be in another setting or elsewhere. That's up to you. I would suggest that you write a method that checks that value and, if it is within the supported range, set the `Interval` of your `Timer` so it `Ticks` at the desired moment. If it is outside the supported range, set the `Interval` to some smaller value and then, when the `Tick` event is raised, you can call that same method again. That way, the you will eventually get a `Tick` raised at the specifically desired moment.

As with all programming problems, you should work out the logic first. Pick up a pen and paper and work out how you would do it manually, without any programming at all. Once you understand the logic, formalise it into an algorithm. You can then write code to specifically implement that algorithm. Don't try to jump from a vague idea directly to code.